# How to create a custom deserializer in Jackson for a generic type?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, deserialization

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class <T> Foo<T> {
    ....
}

class Bar {
    Foo<Something> foo;
}
```

I want to write a custom Jackson deserializer for Foo. In order to do that (for example, in order to deserialize `Bar` class that has `Foo<Something>` property), I need to know the concrete type of `Foo<T>`, used in `Bar`, at deserialization time (e.g. I need to know that `T` is `Something` in that particluar case).

How does one write such a deserializer? It should be possible to do it, since Jackson does it with typed collections and maps.

**Clarifications:**

It seems there are 2 parts to solution of the problem:

1) Obtain declared type of property `foo` inside `Bar` and use that to deserialize `Foo<Somehting>`

2) Find out at deserialization time that we are deserializing property `foo` inside class `Bar` in order to successfully complete step 1)

How does one complete 1 and 2 ?

Comment: You can use reflection to find out that the *declared* type of `foo` is `Foo<Something>`. That's about it. I don't know about Jackson to say if that is a means to your end here. [`Field#getGenericType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType--)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) for your generic type which also implements [`ContextualDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/ContextualDeserializer.html).

For example, suppose we have the following simple wrapper type that contains a generic value:

```
public static class Wrapper<T> {
    public T value;
}
```

We now want to deserialize JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 37
}
```

into an instance of a class that looks like this:

```
public static class Person {
    public Wrapper<String> name;
    public Wrapper<Integer> age;
}
```

Implementing `ContextualDeserializer` allows us to create a specific deserializer for each field in the `Person` class, based on the generic type parameters of the field. This allows us to deserialize the name as a string, and the age as an integer.

The complete deserializer looks like this:

```
public static class WrapperDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Wrapper<?>> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    private JavaType valueType;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        JavaType wrapperType = property.getType();
        JavaType valueType = wrapperType.containedType(0);
        WrapperDeserializer deserializer = new WrapperDeserializer();
        deserializer.valueType = valueType;
        return deserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper<?> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Wrapper<?> wrapper = new Wrapper<>();
        wrapper.value = ctxt.readValue(parser, valueType);
        return wrapper;
    }
}
```

It is best to look at `createContextual` here first, as this will be called first by Jackson. We read the type of the field out of the `BeanProperty` (e.g. `Wrapper<String>`) and then extract the first generic type parameter (e.g. `String`). We then create a new deserializer and store the inner type as the `valueType`.

Once `deserialize` is called on this newly created deserializer, we can simply ask Jackson to deserialize the value as the inner type rather than as the whole wrapper type, and return a new `Wrapper` containing the deserialized value.

In order to register this custom deserializer, we then need to create a module that contains it, and register that module:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
        .addDeserializer(Wrapper.class, new WrapperDeserializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

If we then try to deserialize the example JSON from above, we can see that it works as expected:

```
Person person = objectMapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
System.out.println(person.name.value);  // prints Alice
System.out.println(person.age.value);   // prints 37
```

There are some more details about how contextual deserializers work in the [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureContextualHandlers).

Comment: Thank you for this post. Incredibly helpful to achieve what I wanted. 

I have made a few alterations that works with root values in case anyone else from Google comes around. https://gist.github.com/darylteo/a7be65b539c0d8d3ca0de94d96763f33

Comment: Thank you, that really helped
The contextual type itself could be generic, in that case property will be null,  you need to create the JsonDeserializer using the ctxt.getContextualType

Comment: What happens when value inside Wrapper is private, and is set by a constructor with arguments?

Comment: Thank you, this really helped in writing a custom deserialiser for Quantity<Length> and Quantity<Speed> types. Helped in figuring out which type in use.

Comment: I am having an issue if the Generic is inside a list. 
I am getting NPE and the readTree looks better. Any chance to include this at the answer ?

Comment: Is this solution thread safe...? We instantiate WrapperDeserializer & add it to the module, if multiple requests came in parallel isn't there the risk that we could refer to the wrong JavaType ?

Answer (score 8):

If the target itself is a generic type then property will be null, for that you'll need to get the valueTtype from the DeserializationContext:

```
@Override
public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    if (property == null) { //  context is generic
        JMapToListParser parser = new JMapToListParser();
        parser.valueType = ctxt.getContextualType().containedType(0);
        return parser;
    } else {  //  property is generic
        JavaType wrapperType = property.getType();
        JavaType valueType = wrapperType.containedType(0);
        JMapToListParser parser = new JMapToListParser();
        parser.valueType = valueType;
        return parser;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone getting an NPE on the accepted answer, this solution is probably what you need.  Thankyou - I have no idea how much time you just saved me.

Comment: Definitely extremely helpful. I was actually using this in Kotlin, and there are a few caveats. For example, generic type information can be passed incompletely depending on how you read the value: `mapper.readValue<Generic<T>>` preserves the inner type T, while the Java method `mapper.readValue(json, Generic::class.java)` does not. Somehow obvious, yet caused some NPEs.

This exercise taught me quite a bit about generics in JVM.

Comment: @TheOperator do you have an example please ?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can access/resolve {targetClass} for a Custom Jackson Deserializer. Of course you need to implement ContextualDeserializer interface for this.

```
public class WPCustomEntityDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> 
              implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<?> targetClass;

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        //Your code here to customize deserialization
        // You can access {target class} as targetClass (defined class field here)
        //This should build some {deserializedClasObject}

        return deserializedClasObject;

    }   

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property){
        //Find here the targetClass to be deserialized  
        String targetClassName=ctxt.getContextualType().toCanonical();
        try {
            targetClass = Class.forName(targetClassName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, none of the above solutions worked, so I had to write a custom module. You can find my implementation [on GitHub](https://github.com/Alwinator/StringListJsonTrimmer).

I wanted to write a deserializer that automatically removes blank Strings from Lists.