# how to serialize a general object to Json and deserialize Json to the object in Java

Tags: java, serialization, cassandra, deserialization

Is there a way to serialize a general object to Json and deserialize Json to the object?
If the object is an entity, I can use `Jackson 2` lib to achieve the purpose.
But if the object is a general class, how can I do this?

For example, I'd like to serialize `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update` to Json and save it to DB, then search and deserialize it to `Update` object, finally use it as the argument of `com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Statement)` to execuate.

Is it possible to reproduce `Update` object?

**COMPLEMENT**:

My real purpose is to store `Update` and then retrieve and execute it. So I thought I could save it as `JSON String` and then retrieve and deserialize it into the original `Update` instance and execute it. If It's not a good way, how can I store `Update` and then retrieve and execute it?
Though I can store the `text query` of `Update` and the retrieve and execute the `text query`, some other information in `Update` maybe lose, like `ConsistencyLevel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Convert the `QueryBuilder.update` into string using `toString()` method**

If you want to store,retrieve and execute the `QueryBuilder.update` query, you don't have to serialized and deserialized it into json.

```
String query = QueryBuilder.update("exp").with(QueryBuilder.set("data", "This is a test data")).toString();
//Now you can store the text query directly to cassandra
//And retrieve the text query
session.execute(query); //Execute the query
```

Here is the code of `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    try {
        if (forceNoValues)
            return getQueryString();
        // 1) try first with all values inlined (will not work if some values require custom codecs,
        // or if the required codecs are registered in a different CodecRegistry instance than the default one)
        return maybeAddSemicolon(buildQueryString(null, CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE)).toString();
    } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
        // 2) try next with bind markers for all values to avoid usage of custom codecs
        try {
            return maybeAddSemicolon(buildQueryString(new ArrayList<Object>(), CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE)).toString();
        } catch (RuntimeException e2) {
            // Ugly but we have absolutely no context to get the registry from
            return String.format("built query (could not generate with default codec registry: %s)", e2.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that It's returning the actual query string

Comment: Yes, I want to store, retrieve and execute the `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update` query.
You mean using `toString()` method can get the correct text query and then execute it directly?  
Are you sure this is correct regarding **complex** update operation?  
I don't know what `toString()` method exactly do. The source code is a little diffcult for me.

Comment: Though I can get the text query, I maybe lose some other information in `Update`.

Comment: @niaomingjian Updated the answer added `toString()` code. You can see that It's returning the actual query string.

Comment: Will it lose other information, like `ConsistencyLevel`, that was set in `Update`? I'm afraid of that.

Comment: It only contains the query. consistency,defaultTimestamp etc will be lost

Comment: I think so, too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you can *always* look into creating your *own* custom (de)serializer code.

See [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159677/how-to-create-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson-for-a-generic-type) for further reading.

Meaning: you can look into the implementation of the class you intend to "serialize"; and then write code that works for that implementation.

The major downside when doing that for 3rd party code is: you now have to keep track of changes to that 3rd party code; as changes to that *Update* class for example might easily break your custom (de)serializer code.

Comment: My real purpose is to store `Update` and then retrieve and execute it. So I wonder if I can use Json format to store it. Are there other ways to do that?

Comment: I gave you input that describes how to store objects of  arbitrary classes. I really don't get your point. There is no magic here. *You* have to look into the implementation of the class you intend to serialize and then write code. The only alternative I can think if: Google gson works using reflection, so it does not need the getter/setter methods that Jackson expects. But then it sounds like you are overburdened anyway. Finally: you find all the answers worth "repeating" your question, but none of them is good enough for an upvote? Very motivating...

Answer (score 0):

[org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) offers a simple API that manipulates json.
There is a method that creates a JSONObject of an instance of a class based on its getter.
For example:

```
public class MyClass{
    private int id;
    private String name,

    public MyClass(int id_, String name_) {
        this.id = id_;
        this.name = name_;
    }

    public int getId() { return this.id; }
    public int getName() { return this.name; }

    //Create a JSONObject with a key-value for each getter of your class
    public JSONObject toJson(){
        return new JSONObject(this);
    }
}
```

Then, in your code :

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(1, "doe");
JSONObject json = obj.toJson();
System.out.println(json.toString());
// -> print : {"id":1,"name":"doe"}
```

The API also provides differents parser, and you can code a constructor of your class with a JSONObject provided :

```
public MyClass(JSONObject json){
     this.id= json.getInt("id");
     this.name= json.getString("name");
}
```

Full doc at : [org.json official doc](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/)

Comment: My real purpose is to store `Update` and then retrieve and execute it.
And `Update` is the 3rd party code, not mine.

Comment: Does your `Update` object contains getters ? If so, my method still work.