# Jackson Deserializer List Generic Type with ContextualDeserializer

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I have this json object

```
[
  {"name": "Alice","age": 37},
  {"name": "Bob","age": 37}
]
```

I saw this example and it works, how can I adapt it to a List of People

[How to create a custom deserializer in Jackson for a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159677/how-to-create-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson-for-a-generic-type)

```
    public static class Wrapper<T> {
       public T value;
    }

    public class People {
        public List<Person> people;
    }

    public class Person {
        public Wrapper<String> name;
        public Wrapper<Integer> age;
    }
```

I would like to use `JsonDeserialize` and `ContextualDeserializer` to deserialize a Json object with a list of people using java generic type so you can use the class for other objects

```
public static class WrapperDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Wrapper<?>> 
       implements ContextualDeserializer {
    ...........

        }
```

and get List of People

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
        .addDeserializer(Wrapper.class, new WrapperDeserializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

String json = "[{ \"name\": \"Alice\",\"age\": 37},{ \"name\": \"Bob\",\"age\": 37}]";

People people = objectMapper.readValue(json, People.class);
```