# Using the instantiated collection type for Jackson deserialization instead of initializing a new one?

Tags: java, jackson

If I have a class

```
class DTO {
    final MySet<Types> values = MySetWrapper(EnumSet.of(Types.class));

    public MySet getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

where `MySet` extends `Set`. Jackson complains that

```
Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type MySet
```

which I understand, but I already instantiated the collection. What I want is for jackson to just call `add` for each value after it created an instance, something like:

```
DTO o = new DTO();
MySet<Types> values = o.getValues();
for (Types type : jsonArray) {
    values.add(type );
}
```

I don't want it to try to create a new collection itself.

Comment: Is adding a custom deserializer an option ?

Comment: @Coder Yes. I have a solution currently that looks like the accepted answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159677/how-to-create-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson-for-a-generic-type). But even there in the `deserialize` method I need to create the instance *again* myself. Also I don't want ALL of my `MySet` to be instantiated that way. I could have a `MySetWrapper` wrap some other set implementation. Regadless of what's on the right side, the left one is a set and should be treated as a regular set.

Comment: Have you tried using @JsonCreator for your DTO class? With a factory method/ constructor annotated as a creator in Jackson, you can define the object deserialization strategy for DTO.class. Here's a simple example : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-creator.html

Comment: @ArpanKanthal the problem is that as much as i know if i do that i would need to manually set all the other fields in my class which are otherwise fine. I want only special treatment for this field, not the whole class.

Comment: @Mark  another way i can think of is using a @ JsonSetter annotation to do what you need to . Let me know if that helps

Comment: @ArpanKanthal I managed to make it work with `@JsonProperty`, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer using [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html):

```
@JsonProperty
private void setValues(Set<Types> types) {
    values.addAll(types);
}
```

Pretty short and simple thankfully.

Edit: seems like you don't even need the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that the `DTO` class is configured (by default or explicitly) to deserialize the `values` part of the JSON input into the DTO `values` field of `DTO` :

```
Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type MySet
```

If you consider that Jackson should not perform the deserialization directly on this field, you could define a constructor to set  `values` and also make sure that Jackson will not perform automatically the deserialization work : to achieve it, remove setter for that field  (or add `@JsonIgnore` on it) and any jackson module that will use reflection to deserialize to fields.

It would give :

```
final MySet<Types> values = MySetWrapper(EnumSet.of(Types.class));

@JsonCreator
public MyFoo(Set<Types> values) { 
    this.values.addAll(values);
}
```

Note that I specified in the constructor `Set` and not `MySet` (should not be an issue as interface doesn't declare fields), otherwise you would get the same issue since you didn't define a deserializer for `MySet`.
But if you implement a deserializer for that you could of course do :

```
public MyFoo(MySet<Types> values) { 
    this.values.addAll(values);
}
```

Comment: "remove setter for that field" it's a final field, there is no setter, only getter.

Comment: Also what about the other fields I have in my class that work fine. If I use this custom constructor would I need to manually set all the other fields, or does jackson know to set after construction everything else?

Comment: You should very probably do that.