How to easily serialize and deserialize maps with null keys with Jackson
I'm using Spring Boot with the autoconfigured objectMapper.
Suppose I need to serialize and deserialize various HashMaps whose keys can be null. AFAIK this is not supported by default. So, how to do it most concisely?
The important part is that objectMapper needs to continue working as it does for every other type.
What I've tried already:

For serialization, I added a custom NullKeySerializer which writes "null" string in case the map key is null (see below). Can it break other java types (not maps) during serializations? Also, maybe a bundled serializer exists somewhere? (I only found com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.key.Jsr310NullKeySerializer but it's marked as deprecated).

objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new JsonSerializer<>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                gen.writeFieldName("null");
            }
        });


For deserialization, the only thing that I've found is to register a module with a custom deserializer.
Looks like you need to specify the return type in this case, so I'm not sure how to do it in case of generic maps (it can be Map<String, String> or Map<Integer, Object> - in any case, "null" string needs to be converted to the "real" null). Again, maybe there is an existing deserializer for this?

Note that I need to use the autoconfigured object mapper from Spring Boot and tune it if needed, so I would appreciate not having answers with new ObjectMapper() or stuff like that. Also, I cannot use annotations like @JsonSerialize on the specific fields, the whole configuration needs to be done in one place only.

The question is about serializing and deserializing nullable keys in maps - of course, I can't ask about only one of these two things since this is a bidirectional process. All other questions are inside the "what I've tried" section which is optional so they can be ignored.

Does this help on creating the generic deserializer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159677/how-to-create-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson-for-a-generic-type

Try to reproduce this test
class NullSerializerTest {

    // serializer class borrowed from https://github.com/pugwoo/woo-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pugwoo/wooutils/json/NullKeySerializer.java
    public class NullKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider unused)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("");
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testMapSerializer() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // create test data
        Map map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("k", "v1");
        map.put(null, "v2");
        // obtain object mapper
        // if mapper already defined in SpringBoot
        // obtain it as @Autowired instead
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // set serializer in obtained object mapper
        objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new NullKeySerializer());
        // serialize test data and print result
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map)); // writes: {"":"v2","k":"v1"}
    }

}


Please provide an explanation which accompanies your code

This is pretty much the same as what I provided in the question (with "" instead of "null"). I'm not sure how to deserialize it back though (assuming that there can be maps of different types)

Your serializer will convert null keys to "null". You need to add below deserializer.
public class NullStringJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String result = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        return result!=null && result.toLowerCase().equals(null+"") ? null : result;
    }
}

and it can be used like this
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new JsonSerializer() {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeFieldName("null");
    }
});

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
        .addDeserializer(String.class, new NullStringJsonDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);


Won't it be applied to all the possible strings though? In my case, I only need to handle null keys in maps (since they're not allowed in json). I mean, serialization is done correctly b/c setNullKeySerializer is designed for this specific case but IMHO, the deserialization part is too broad

Exactly. Jackson key deserializer is not working for this specific case. I know this is not what you are looking for but I think you can create a custom utility class for serialisation and deserialization. For deserialization you can directly convert keys to null from json string only.

Probably it is not perfect answer but I suggest deserialize it as it is (with some unique string substitution instead null)
and then process the resulting map, replacing this key to null.
Here is an example
class NullSerializerTest {

    final String NULL = "this is null key"; // use here something unique key

    // serializer class borrowed from https://github.com/pugwoo/woo-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pugwoo/wooutils/json/NullKeySerializer.java
    public class NullKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider unused)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(NULL); // use something unique for null keys
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testMapSerializer() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // prepare test data
        Map data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("k", "v1");
        data.put(null, "v2");
        // get object mapper, or @Autowire it if already exists in SpringBoot
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new NullKeySerializer());
        // serialize
        String actual = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        // verify
        assertEquals("{\""+NULL+"\":\"v2\",\"k\":\"v1\"}", actual);
        // deserialize into map class
        Map<Object, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(actual, Map.class);
        System.out.println(map.entrySet().size());
        // define resulting map
        final Map<Object, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        // loop on entry set of deserialized map
        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
            result.put(
                // put original key or null if the key is NULL
                e.getKey() instanceof String && NULL.equals(e.getKey()) ? null : e.getKey(),
                // put original value
                e.getValue());
        }
        // verify result, we just print it
        System.out.println(result); // prints:    {null=v2, k=v1}
    }

}

